# What is the antonym of "delegation"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, antonyms

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delegation) defines **delegation** as *"the act of empowering to act for another"*. In such a context, what is the antonym of **delegation**? [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/delegation) suggests **keeping**, which seems a bit weak.

I can think of something like **preservation**, but it could be misinterpreted. Any suggestions?

I am a manager. Some tasks, I might want to delegate. Others, I might want not to. The former are instances of a delegation. What are the latter instances of?

Comment: _Retention_ is fine, but you don't give us very much context. There is an interesting and salient Q&A at our sister site **[here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215118/is-there-an-antonym-for-the-verb-form-of-delegate)**

Comment: Incidentally, I wasn't sure at first what you meant by its opposite - I suppose this is more of a lack of delegation. Another understanding might be "assumption (of responsibility)"

Comment: This kind of question requires the sentence you wish to use the word in. For example, you would not say simply "I retained the task."  Rather you would say "I did not delegate the task." Sometimes the "opposite" requires a negative.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo -- you don't retain tasks, but you do retain authority and powers.

Comment: @Malvolio: Of course. That's why it's important to know what kind of sentence the OP wants to make.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not *delegate* authority, you *retain* authority.  The opposite of *delegation* in this sense is *retention*.

In the comments, someone points out that the opposite action from delegation, reversing delegation, is *centralization*.

*Delegation* originally referred to the sending of ambassadors; the reverse of that is *recalling* ambassadors, but I think if you said you were recalling authority, everyone would think you were just remembering it.