# The Opposite of Delegation

Tags: word-request, antonyms

As opposed to this question [What is the antonym of "delegation"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/132056/what-is-the-antonym-of-delegation), if one is not delegating to a subordinate, but rather asking a superior to take on a task, what would that be called? (other than begging for mercy:)

Answer (score 8):

"Escalation" is the commonly used word in business for passing work to a senior.

From the website *[Business Pundit](http://www.businesspundit.com/encyclopedia/accounting-2/escalation/)*:

> **Escalation as a General Business Term**
>   In business in general, escalation refers to sending a project to a higher level of the organization for resolution. For example, imagine that an organization’s computers are slow. Helpdesk finds the problem, but can’t figure out what’s causing it. So they escalate to the IT department, which looks into the problem. IT realizes the issue has to do with the company’s systems being hacked. While working to fix the problem, IT also escalates it to Operations, which deals with security breaches. The issue may then be escalated to the company’s executives if it proves serious enough.